# <C:IF> Check wether the two paramters are the same or not

Tags: jsp, if-statement, netbeans, derby

I have this if statement two show the picture only if the text in the database is the as the parameter i gave to the page:

```
<c:if test="${row.hozzaadta}==${param.userid}">
       <img src="http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/softwaredemo/PNG/128x128/DeleteRed.png" width="25" height="25">
    </c:if>
```

It is not working, i am pretty sure i am using it wrong, can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is impossible but I'd send the boolean from my `servlet` like this

```
boolean myBool = row.getHozzaadta().equals(param.getUserId());
request.setAttribute("myBool", myBool);
```

And in the `JSP`

```
<c:if test="${ myBool }"></if>
```